# Cannot add keyservers in seahorse

Tags: seahorse, keyserver

I cannot add keyservers in seahorse... When I try to add any keyserver the "ok" button is deactivated...

[image]

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 lts

Answer (score 2):

use dconf-editor:
/desktop/gnome/crypto/pgp/keyservers > custom value (see Default)

Comment: You can reset it from shell to default value with `dconf reset /desktop/gnome/crypto/pgp/keyservers`. If that doesn't help, it is possible that there are wrong defaults in your Seahorse (I had that problem on Arch Linux). In that case you can set it manually with `dconf write /desktop/gnome/crypto/pgp/keyservers "['ldap://keyserver.pgp.com','hkps://keys.openpgp.org']"`